# Permutation Inversion Questions (3)

Tags: combinatorics, abstract-algebra, permutations

Working my way through a combinatorics text and I'm hung up on a couple of questions:

1.) Let $p=p_1 p_2\cdots p_n$ be a permutation.  An inversion of $p$ is a pair of entries $(p_i,p_j)$ so that $i<j$ but $p_i>p_j$.  Let us a call a permutation even (resp. odd) if it has an even (resp. odd) number of inversion.  Prove that the permuation consisting of the one cycle $(a_1a_2\cdots a_k)$ is even if $k$ is odd, and is odd if $k$ is even.

2.)  Let $I(n,k)$ be the number of $n$-permutations that have $k$ inversions.  Prove that $I(n,k)=I(n,\binom{n}{2}-k)$.

3.)  Find an explicit formula for $I(n,3)$.

These are from a combinatorics text, but I vaguely remember this topic popping up in undergrad abstract algebra and possibly in an algorithm design course as well.

Comment: How are permutations being written? Is $p_i$ the image of $i$ under the permutation $p$?

Comment: It's always interesting to see cross-posting from reddit =P

Answer (score 6):

- if the permutation consists of one cycle, (this doesn't seem to have anything to do with inversions), how many repetitions of the cycle will it take to return to identity if $k$ is even? if $k$ is odd?
- for $I(n,k)$, how many total possible inversions are there? How many inversions are there of the reverse of a given permutation?
- for $I(n,3)$, what is $I(n,1)$? $I(n,2)$? Look at some values, guess a formula, and use induction to quickly prove. Or think combinatorially: you have 3 inversions; if they don't interact then it's straightforward; if they do interact then a little more thought on counting them.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate $I(n,3)$ we can use the [generating function](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-count-the-number-of-permutations-that-have-a-given-number-of-inversions),

\begin{aligned}I_{n} &= (1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3) \cdots (1+x+\dots +x^{n-1})
\end{aligned}

For $I(n,3)$ to be nonzero, $n \ge 3$ and we see that $I(3,3) = 1$.

If $n \ge 4$ then we can focus on the combinations within the bracketed multiplicands of $I_n$ to 'pull out' the $x^3$ contributions.

$\quad \text{Selecting $x$ three times } \quad\quad\quad\quad\;= \binom{n-1}{3}$
$\quad \text{Selecting $x^2$ first and then $x$ next } = (n-2) \cdot (n-2)$
$\quad \text{Selecting $x^3$ once } \;\,\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\;= \binom{n-3}{1}$

So

$$I(n,3) = \binom{n-1}{3} + (n-2) \cdot (n-2) + n - 3$$