# Prove combinatorically that the permutation consisting of the one cycle $(a_1a_2···a_k)$ is even if k is odd, and is odd if k is even.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, permutations

Let $p = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$ be a permutation. An $\textbf{inversion}$ of $p$ is a pair of entries $(p_i, p_j)$ so that $i < j$ but $p_i > p_j$. Let us call a permutation $\textit{even}$ (resp. $\textit{odd}$) if it has an even (resp. odd) number of inversions.\
Prove that the permutation consisting of the one cycle $(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_k)$ is even if $k$ is odd, and is odd if $k$ is even.

I have been recommended solving this problem using either induction or the inclusion-exclusion principle but I am not sure how either apply. [Permutation Inversion Questions (3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25712/permutation-inversion-questions-3) I have seen this question get answered but I am not sure how to interpret/formulate this information into a proof. Any suggestions would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The parity of a permutation is equal to the parity of the number of factors when the permutation is written as a product of transpositions. Show that an $n$-cycle can be written as a product of $n-1$ transpositions. You can do this by giving an explicit representation $\sigma=\tau_1\tau_2\cdots \tau_{n-1}$, where $\tau_i$ is a transposition depending on $\sigma$, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Alternatively, you can show that an $n$-cycle $\sigma$ can be written $$\sigma=\tilde \sigma \cdot \tau,$$ where $\tilde\sigma$ is an $(n-1)$-cycle and $\tau$ is a transposition. This lets you prove that $n$-cycles can be written as a product of $(n-1)$ transpositions by induction on $n$.

For example, $(1\;2\;3)=(1\;2)(2\;3)$, where the permutations in a product are applied right to left.

Comment: Proving the [first statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation#Equivalence_of_the_two_definitions) seems somewhat involved, but maybe it is unavoidable given how easily the problem can be solved with the "parity of number of transpositions" definition?